# Неизвестный идентификатор в запросе из таблицы DUAL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select x from dual
```

этот запрос выдает ошибку:

> ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier

Хорошо, понятно, идентификатор X у меня нигде не объявлен.

Но почему этот запрос выполняется нормально:

```
select n from dual
```

Что это за неизвестный но валидный идентификатор? Откуда он берется?

Также работает и запрос:

```
select q, y, s, d, n, m from dual
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Воспроизводится в SQL*Plus:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: dual это таблица? Может там присутствуют поля q y s d n m и не присутствует x?

Comment: Да, это стандартная оракловая таблица, она имеет один столбец DUMMY и одну строку

Comment: А у вас этот запрос просто в каком то средстве передачи запросов вроде sql*plus выполняется. Это не какой нибудь pl/sql код, вроде хранимой процедуры или пакета ? Я вот только что проверил на oracle.live (там 19c версия) и ни один из идентификаторов не объявлен и запрос не работает

Comment: Этот запрос я отправляю из PL/SQL Developer

Comment: Не удалось повторить указанное поведение в Pl\Sql Developer `ORA-00904: "N": недопустимый идентификатор`

Comment: @4per, добавил демонстрацию

Comment: @Kromster Поправил заголовок. Так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DUAL` это физическая таблица содержащая только одну колонку `dummy` и только одну запись со значением `'X'`. Ни каких других колонок в ней не существует:

```sql
SQL> select * from dual;

DUMMY
-----
X

SQL> select n from dual;
select n from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "N": invalid identifier
```

Но в качестве столбца может быть указано любое действительное для листа запроса выражение. Например, для вызова функции без параметров скобоки не обязательны, и такое выражение ничем не отличается от колонки таблицы.

Проверить наличие таковых по имени можно запросом:

```sql
select owner, object_name, object_type 
from all_objects where object_name = 'N';
```

Comment: Добавил демонстрацию

Comment: @АндрейNOP Чудес не бывает. Посмотрите план запроса, увидите что действительно отправляется на сервер - `select * from table (dbms_xplan.display_cursor ());`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вы можете воспроизвети данное поведение в обчном консольном `sqlplus` (вместо `PL/SQL Developer`)? И еще - что выводит `DESC dual;`?

Comment: @MaxU, да, добавил.

Comment: @АндрейNOP  Ну ещё это - `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'N'`

Comment: @0xdb, урря! Оказывается это имена функций в нашей базе! Непонятно только кто и зачем их сделал :D

Comment: Непонятно только что теперь делать с этим вопросом. Может поправите ответ с указанием информации о том как можно проверить идентификаторы? Типа как в вашем предыдущем комментарии...

Comment: @АндрейNOP  Я так и подумал, что это функции. Студенты наверное поупрожнялись. Расширю конечно ответ.

Comment: Примечательно, что функцию без параметров можно вызывать без указания скобок